# Is it possible to remember the previous redirect action in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Let me explain my scenario. I have a few different products in my website, and users are able to buy them using PayPal. I have already configured PayPal to work with my website, and I have something like this in my `Web.config` file for redirection from PayPal:

```
<add key="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/PayPal/RedirectFromPaypal" />
```

So, the point is that, for each different product, once the payment is done, I need to do something different. For one, I need to write to the database, for the other I need to do some calculation and show it to the user, for the last one I need to send an e-mail.

The point is that, when the user presses the order button, from whichever product type, he/she is redirected to PayPal to finish the order, once the user finishes the order, gets redirected back to `PayPal/RedirectFromPaypal` view. But, as I said once before, for different product types I have different requirements, therefore, I need to somehow know which order action initiated the order, and then when I reach the RedirectToPaypal method, I can act accordingly. Is it possible to somehow remember it? Please also note that I used this [tutorial](http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration/) for connecting my app with PayPal. And also note that I have three different action methods for the three different order types.

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult ValidateCommand(string product, string totalPrice)

public ActionResult ValidateCommandAd(Ad ad)

public ActionResult ValidateCommandSearch(Search search)
```

Each particular action is called for each particular product order. Inside, I just set up some values for PayPal, and then redirect the user to the PayPal. Then, when it comes to the action below, I want to know which action was previously called, I mean before redirecting to PayPal, and getting back from PayPal to NotifyFromPaypal, so I can do the relevant coding in the below action:

```
    public ActionResult NotifyFromPaypal()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Any idea and code samples that will help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give PayPal the return URL add a parameter that will tell the receiving action which order action it came from.

IE: `http://www.mywebsite.com/PayPal/RedirectFromPaypal?type=orderAction`

---

**Update from comments:**

Steps:

1. User creates an order in your system.
2. You redirect them to PayPal for payment and give PayPal the callback URL with the new parameter that has the "order action type".

   - Note: You can add as many parameters as you need to identify the order on callback. *Keep in mind this a rough example.*
3. Write a controller action that consumes that request.

---

```
public class PayPal : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RedirectFromPaypal(string type)
    {
        // PayPal calls this action on order completion.
        // I made "type" a string for this example but it can be anything.
        // Add other parameters as needed.

        // Processing, etc.
        return View();
    }
}
```